# d3-graphviz: incorrect rendering if I use same graphviz renderer to draw slightly different graph multiple times

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graphviz

I was using d3-graphviz to draw interactive graphs. I found that, somehow using the same graphviz renderer created at the beginning to re-draw new/updated graph leads to the wrong layout. For example, if I do the following steps, it would go wrong:

1. Create the index.html, including the d3, d3-graphviz and viz we need to use.
2. Use renderDot() function with specific callback.
3. Call renderDot() again to draw another one, with multi-line, bold font label
4. Render again with renderDot() to generate the same graph we have in step 2

I am supposed to get at the very end, again:

[image: expected graph]

However Last step (step 4) results in a wrong layout graph. The nodes and edges won't be placed in the right positions:

[image: wrong layout]

Also note that, after step 3, if I click on the svg, it would shift upwards (one direction) a bit, which is also weird. After we clicking on it, it looks like this:

[image: shifted upwards after svg being clicked]

Here are the source code:

***index.html:***

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src=https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js></script>
<script src=https://unpkg.com/viz.js@1.8.0/viz.js></script>
<script src=https://unpkg.com/d3-graphviz@1.5.0/build/d3-graphviz.min.js></script>

<!-- Main Graph -->
<div id="graph" style="text-align: center;" height=3200px width=3200px></div>

</body>
```

***render.js:***

```
<!-- language: typescript -->

// please run below code step by step

// create renderer
x = d3.select('#graph').graphviz()

// 1st rendering
x.renderDot(`
digraph {
    node [style="filled"]
    0 [id="0" label="honda::models"]
    1 [id="1" label="hidden"]
    2 [id="2" label="hidden"]
    0 -> 1 [id="0->1" label=""]
    0 -> 2 [id="0->2" label=""]
}
`, function() {
    d3.selectAll('text')._groups[0].forEach(function(e) {
        if (ans=/(.+?\: ).+/.exec(e.innerHTML)) {
            e.innerHTML = ans[0].replace(ans[1],
                "<tspan font-weight=bold>" + ans[1] + "</tspan>");
        }
    })
});

// 2nd rendering (bold and multi-line text label)
x.renderDot(`
digraph {
    node [style="filled"]
    0 [id="0" label="honda::models"]
    1 [id="1" label="name: fit\\linventory id: 007"]
    2 [id="2" label="hidden"]
    0 -> 1 [id="0->1" label=""]
    0 -> 2 [id="0->2" label=""]
}
`, function() {
    d3.selectAll('text')._groups[0].forEach(function(e) {
        if (ans=/(.+?\: ).+/.exec(e.innerHTML)) {
            e.innerHTML = ans[0].replace(ans[1],
                "<tspan font-weight=bold>" + ans[1] + "</tspan>");
        }
    })
});

// 3rd rendering
x.renderDot(`
digraph {
    node [style="filled"]
    0 [id="0" label="honda::models"]
    1 [id="1" label="hidden"]
    2 [id="2" label="hidden"]
    0 -> 1 [id="0->1" label=""]
    0 -> 2 [id="0->2" label=""]
}
`, function() {
    d3.selectAll('text')._groups[0].forEach(function(e) {
        if (ans=/(.+?\: ).+/.exec(e.innerHTML)) {
            e.innerHTML = ans[0].replace(ans[1],
                "<tspan font-weight=bold>" + ans[1] + "</tspan>");
        }
    })
});
```

You can replicate it by creating the index.html, and then running the code in javascript step by step.

Note: I've left the callback function there, which updates the font if it sees patterns "text: xxx" in each line. It makes no difference in the "hidden" case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to make the subsequent renderings in the callbacks.
2. The manipulation of the DOM you make to get bold fonts messes things up. Make it with pure attribute settings instead.

I made these changes in the code below and also added a transition so you clearly can see what's going on without running the code step by step.

The code represents what I think your code would have done if it was correct. See my comments in the code about setting bold font initially if that's what you really want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src=https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js></script>
<script src=https://unpkg.com/viz.js@1.8.0/viz.js></script>
<script src=https://unpkg.com/d3-graphviz@1.5.0/build/d3-graphviz.min.js></script>

<!-- Main Graph -->
<div id="graph" style="text-align: center;" height=3200px width=3200px></div>

<script>
  // create renderer
x = d3.select('#graph').graphviz()
  .transition(function () {return d3.transition().duration(2000)})
// replace the font-weight settings below with this if you want a bold font already from the start
//  .on("transitionStart", function() {d3.selectAll('text').attr("font-weight", "bold");});

  // 1st rendering
x.renderDot(`
digraph {
    node [style="filled"]
    0 [id="0" label="honda::models"]
    1 [id="1" label="hidden"]
    2 [id="2" label="hidden"]
    0 -> 1 [id="0->1" label=""]
    0 -> 2 [id="0->2" label=""]
}
`, function() {
    d3.selectAll('text').attr("font-weight", "bold");

    // 2nd rendering (bold and multi-line text label)
    x.renderDot(`
    digraph {
        node [style="filled"]
        0 [id="0" label="honda::models"]
        1 [id="1" label="name: fit\\linventory id: 007"]
        2 [id="2" label="hidden"]
        0 -> 1 [id="0->1" label=""]
        0 -> 2 [id="0->2" label=""]
    }
    `, function() {
        d3.selectAll('text').attr("font-weight", "bold");
        // 3rd rendering
        x.renderDot(`
        digraph {
            node [style="filled"]
            0 [id="0" label="honda::models"]
            1 [id="1" label="hidden"]
            2 [id="2" label="hidden"]
            0 -> 1 [id="0->1" label=""]
            0 -> 2 [id="0->2" label=""]
        }
        `, function() {
            d3.selectAll('text').attr("font-weight", "bold");

        });
    });
});

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 3 questions: 
1) When you mentioned it was my manipulation of DOM to get bold fonts that messed things up, all the html source code seemed to be good. Then how could you tell it was because of this?

2) I use <tspan> because I need to make the word before ":" bold, and sometimes we have multiple lines (your sol doesn't resolve this).

3) I've extended it with click events to trigger those subsequent renderings. I see how you perfectly embed one inside another (using callback). When I need to add ".on('click', ...)" events, I think I would run into the same problem?

Comment: And simply because my use case or desired features mentioned above, I have to use <tspan>, along with adding click event listeners. Is there anyway which works beautifully?

Comment: 1. Simply because I removed and then it worked. d3-graphviz attaches data on every element in the graph that are related in a hierarchy and I think that it got messed up because you broke that hierarchy, but it just a speculation. I haven't investigated it thoroughly.
2. What's your question? My solution should affect *all* text elements. Is there something special with ":"? I have to try myself, but I have not time right now.
3. I don't understand. Show me an example.

Comment: Regarding your last question, again, I don't understand. Show me an example.